# Term for either the Earth's Moon or Sun?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

Is there a term (compound word or phrase would be acceptable)  one could use to refer to either the Moon or the Sun depending on the time of day? Other than the big shiny thing in the sky.

I'd use it in a sentence like: "The Sun/Moon is green because..."

The Sun is a star and the Moon Earth's satellite so I can't say planet or star. They both emit strong light toward the Earth so maybe there's something about that.

Comment: They're both celestial bodies.

Comment: The Moon does not emit any light, strong or weak or otherwise. It merely reflects light emitted by others. At any rate, I am not sure at all what you're trying to say with your sentence. It's either the Sun or the Moon you're talking about. So name it, then. What is the point of jumping through hoops to obscure its identity. I am quite puzzled.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The Moon does not emit any light, but it is the main source of natural light when it’s up, and by far the most prevalent celestial body – two features it shares with the Sun and with no other celestial body. I don’t see why it must be “either the Sun or the Moon you’re talking about” – as a concept, ‘the big shiny thing in the sky’ is quite clear and unambiguous, and I am quite puzzled that it puzzles you. I’m quite puzzled as to why it would be described as green, which neither the Sun nor the Moon is, but looking for a word to cover both seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If the question “Is there an English term that subsumes the Sun and the Moon?” is not about English as described in the help centre, what do you consider it about? It is quite well-established that “is there a term for [notion]” is an on-topic type question to ask here. The question could include more details of prior research, but I cannot see any way this is not about English language and usage.

Comment: Try luminous orb.  Of course the moon looks orb-like only when it is full, but we all know it is an orb.

Comment: Twin cirques of gold and silver drawn /  Both lamps of heav'n upon us shone.

Comment: @Janus The answers are almost certain to be well and truly in the astronomical domain (so the question would belong on the AstronomySE site, under 'terminology'), poetic / whimsical ('twin cirques of gold and silver drawn / Both lamps of heav'n', so 'Literature' is the correct place), or mundane / hypermundane ('celestial bodies' / major sources of natural light // 'big shiny things in the sky'; there _is_ no correct place on SE).

Comment: @Edwin None of that would make it off-topic here. The fact that the question may be on-topic elsewhere does not preclude that it is also on-topic here. And you’d need to **know** what the answer is in order to make the judgement call whether there is a (general) English term for the concept, which would negate the need to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: God I didn't expect this extremely simple question to create such a fuss. @ab2 Orb works perfectly in my case, and I'll try to describe it as a celestial body down the line to be extra clear what I'm talking about. Thank you everybody who didn't try to close my question for random reasons!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> They're both celestial bodies. – Hot Licks
>
> Try luminous orb. Of course the moon looks orb-like only when it is full, but we all know it is an orb. – ab2
>
> Orb works perfectly in my case, and I'll try to describe it as a celestial body down the line to be extra clear what I'm talking about. – Halhex